# JavaScript или jQuery. Получить все параметры объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Выбираем объект селектором

```
$('#inventory_bots').children().first()
```

Получаем такой объект в результате
[image: объект]
Если я хочу, напрмер, получить переменную `dir`, я могу просто написать так:

```
$('#inventory_bots').children().first()["0"].dir
```

и получу то, что мне нужно.
А если параметр, который мне нужно получить называется `jQuery310096473696913211022` и каждый раз эти цифры разные.
Теперь вопрос: Как можно получить список параметров объекта, чтобы потом, например, проверить название параметра через `indexOf("jQuery")` и спокойно получить данные параметра?

Comment: а зачем может понадобится этот параметр? Больше похоже на то, что так ты пытаешься решить какую-то совсем другую задачу

Comment: @Grundy нет, всё верно. Дело в том что я пишу расширение для Chrome. На сайте, где расширение работает, данные что мне нужны спрятаны в PopUp окне. Окно не является частью DOM, а функция Hover. Название функции как я писал меняется

Comment: Все верно, ты пытаешься решить другую проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отобразить элементы, перебрав объект, например:

```
var obj = window.navigator;
for (key in obj){console.log(obj[key])}
```

Comment: http://www.puzzleweb.ru/javascript/15_arrays.php

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо))